# Как настроить переключение раскладки клавиатуры в Ubuntu 20.04 LTS на Alt+Shift?

Tags: ubuntu

Как настроить переключение раскладки клавиатуры в Ubuntu 20.04 LTS на  Alt+Shift ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Устанавливаем **gnome-tweaks** (если не меняли **gnome** на **xfce** или что-то другое) и далее в нем находим раздел `Keyboard & Mouse`, кликаем `Additional Layout Options`, открываем ветку `Switching to another layout`, ставим "птицу" (на всякий случай, есть отдельный пункт для левых <kbd>Alt</kbd> и <kbd>Shift</kbd>) и напоследок делаем рестарт.

Comment: Работает ! Почему в Линуксе такие простые вещи сделаны так сложно и не удобно ? :(

Comment: Обрезание базового функционала упрощает сопровождение сложного проекта, и это происходит не только в Линуксе - шок от Windows 8 до сих пор в памяти.